# Checking debug/release build

Tags: android

i need to check the build in DEBUG/RELEASE in android on run time.
I have search some way for it but not working efficiently for like reading PKG and getting information for it.

Comment: Sorry Anup but I can't really understand what you are trying to do. Try to rephrase your question, maybe we can help you then.

Comment: means you want to check whether the app is installed using DEBUG build or RELEASE Build?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to check if an app signature is debug or published?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4134197/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-an-app-signature-is-debug-or-published)

Answer (score 0):

you can check the application whether it is release mode or debug mode

```
boolean isDebuggable = (0 != (getApplicationInfo().flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_DEBUGGABLE));
```