# Android setting development or production environment

Tags: android

I have an Android project that is communicating with an API. However, the API URL is hardcoded into the code.

Coming from a Rails background, it is possible to communicate to a staging server or a production server based on the Rails environment on which is defined in a config file.

I found `BuildConfig.java` which contains a `DEBUG` variable but warns:

`/** Automatically generated file. DO NOT MODIFY */`

How can I determine which server to communicate to with Android with best practice? Is there a config file to do so?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23844716/640731) answer might give you some ideas. You will have to add a run time check to switch between different urls

Comment: @Krishnabhadra I got the idea that I should be using `BuildConfig.DEBUG`. However, seeing as there is no config directory in the project, I am wondering whether I should create one. I don't believe it is best practice to just run an if statement in the source file to choose one URL or the other.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android - switching between Development and Production Web Services](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10486189/android-switching-between-development-and-production-web-services)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **Product Flavors** for your app i.e. one flavor for `dev`, another for `staging` and another for `production`. Give unique `applicationId` for each flavor.

Then in your code, check what product flavor you're using by checking the value of `BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID` and set the base url accordingly.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

You can use different Base Url for both staging server or a production server from Rails .And on testing for Staging put the Staging URl and in main Put the Production URl.
exp:
http://stage.example.com/filename.

http://example.com/filename.