# Getting certificate details from an apk

Tags: android, certificate, signing

How do I go about getting the details of the certificate an apk was signed with. I have a bunch of apks signed with different certificates and I am trying to group them based on their certificate.

I can get the certificate expiry details using the jarsigner and complete my task but I was curious if I can get any more details or extract the public key ( I believe it stored in META-INF/cert.RSA but it's not readable )

Comment: You can do it [runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7632973/967142) by extracting the X509Certificate from the app(s) - should also give you the public key I assume.

Comment: I would like to do it without code ( Please don't hurt me stackoverflow )

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to view the identity of person who signed the apk on Android device?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324120/how-to-view-the-identity-of-person-who-signed-the-apk-on-android-device)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Try the following:

```
openssl pkcs7 -inform DER -in CERT.RSA -noout -print_certs -text
```

Comment: You can get some info also with java's `keytool`: `keytool -printcert -file CERT.RSA`, but `openssl` is more verbose, that's why I prefer it.

Comment: Thank you. Out of curiosity, which part of the output is the fingerprint? I tried this with the Signal APK (https://signal.org/android/apk/) by extracting META-INF/CERTIFIC.RSA but cannot find a value in the output that matches the Signal fingerprint listed on their site.

Comment: @iangetz see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54782328/apksigner-does-not-verify-signature

Answer (score 51):

`unzip -p Name-of-apk.apk META-INF/CERT.RSA | keytool -printcert` is what I used .

It produces information such as the **owner**, **issuer**, **serial number**, **valid through**, **certificate fingerprints**, **signature algorithms** and **version**.

Answer (score 36):

The easiest of all:

```
keytool -printcert -jarfile file.apk
```

This also works for Android App Bundles (.aab)

Comment: I have been using this command since long time now. Recently I have noticed that `keytool` has stopped showing MD5 in output. Any guesses why is it so ? Tried searching a lot but no success.

Comment: Add -v to get MD5 as well.

Comment: same output. no MD5 visible. :( 
This is so strange. Earlier I used to get MD5 as well. I am simply clueless about why this is happening now.

Comment: I also tried asking question regarding this but again no success. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55336382/md5-missing-from-keytool-command-when-fired-for-apk/

Answer (score 25):

Based on the existing answers, here's the command line for on-the-fly usage of `openssl` *(unzip & pipe the cert instead of defining an `-infile` option)*:

```
unzip -p App.apk META-INF/CERT.RSA |openssl pkcs7 -inform DER -noout -print_certs -text
```

Comment: there is no SHA1

Answer (score 20):

without unpacking you can use ApkSigner from Android SDK and following:

```
apksigner.jar verify --print-certs myApplication.apk
```

Comment: Great answer. Note that starting from Android 7, a new signing scheme was introduced (V2) that will produce APK files without CERT.RSA. So the old methods (that use openssl / keytool) will not work. (see: https://source.android.com/security/apksigning/v2 )

Comment: Also be aware that you have to run it from your tools lib dir: java -jar ~/android-sdk/build-tools/28.0.0-rc1/lib/apksigner.jar

Comment: @DavidLev So, this command gives us the value we can compare, right? But I think I'm a bit lost.. What should I do with this value with the resulting byte[] value from "msgDigest.digest(sigs[0].toByteArray())"?.