# Extract signing information from .apk file

Tags: android, apk, android-keystore

This is *NOT* a request to extract the private key from a .apk file.

I am having a problem signing a new .apk file with same key as the old .apk.  This is important to do because it is required by Google in order to update the app in Google Play.

I am "sure" that I have the keystore file and passwords, but I am still having a problem.

One of the debugging steps I would like to perform is extracting any information about the key from the old .apk file.  I know I cannot get the private key itself (for obvious reasons).  I just want to see the name or other information so I can do a sanity check on getting the keys to match.

My questions are:
1) What information can be extracted from a .apk file regarding key and keystore used to sign it?
2) How do I extract that information?

My preferred platform is Mac, but I can use Linux or Windows as well.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11361452/getting-certificate-details-from-an-apk

Comment: "I am "sure" that I have the keystore file and passwords" : Well if you don't have them you'd know about it as the export process couldn't even start. "but I am still having a problem." : Simply saying "having a problem" doesn't help much. What problem? Where does it fail? What errors are you getting?

Comment: @Squonk - quite obviously, the issue is not that they poster doesn't have *a* keystore, but rather that they may not have (or be using) *the one which was used* to sign the original, and that they want to check if it is, independently of the play store's check.

Comment: @ChrisStratton : My primary point was with "still having a problem". The problem hasn't been explained. Stating "having a problem signing a new .apk file with same key as the old .apk." doesn't clarify whether or not the actual exporting/signing is failing or if it succeeds and the upload to Google Play is failing as a result of a key mismatch. I was asking for clarification of what the "problem" is.

Comment: @Squonk : My questions end in question mark and are enumerated.  "Still having a problem" is incidental to my question.  If this is still distracting anyone I could remove any reference that I am having a problem and just ask the question.  It is the two questions that make my request unique from the many other similar questions.