# Package conflicts with an existing package by the same name(Not prefare to Uninstall)

Tags: android

I'm trying to install new apk for application that I uploaded on play store .. but I got this message (the Package conflicits with an existing package by the same name )
and not able to install application berfor uninstall the past app.. 
what should I do ? 
I won't to force Uninstall on users ..

Comment: Hi, have you managed to fix the problem? Can you share your findings?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I'm guessing:

When you upload an apk to Google Play you have to sign it with a proper keystore, resulting in a package-certificate pair. That apk goes with a particular version & version code number, let's suppose 1.0 / 1

If you upload then a version 1.1 to Google Play, you also have to increment the version code. Doing this, downloading the new apk is just an updating, and there is no problem at all. For the system, the app is the same because the certificate and the package are the same.

That is the normal behavior your users will experience.

Now, I'm guessing you are launching your debug apk in your device while developing, which by default uses the machine debug certificate. If you have that debug apk installed when trying to download the deployed version from Google Play, the system needs you to uninstall the previous one, as they are not the same app (different certificate) and the conflict exists.

That's only a guessing, but give it a try. 
Regards.

Comment: I'm trying to install generated signed apk with the same key store and not available to install

Comment: With the little information I have I only can say that same package + same keystore is installable without the need of uninstalling the previous apk, so keep looking because the issue is probably related to that. Just in the unlikly case that there is an error in the device system, try in another one and check that the error remains. If the problem is still there, then check https://stackoverflow.com/a/11384475/4360308 It has info about using openssl to get the sign information of an apk file, so extract both apks that are giving you the error and compare the output. Regards.