# MD5 missing from `keytool` command when fired for APK

Tags: android, certificate, apk, keytool

Usually I fetch Android Package (APK) Certificate information using the below command :

```
keytool -printcert -jarfile <APK>
```

but recently I have noticed that MD5 column is missing from the output. 
I just get `SHA1` and `SHA256` as seen in output below :

```
Getting Certification Info.
---------------------
Owner: CN=XYZ
Issuer: CN=XYZ
Serial number: 4e98b743
Valid from: Wed Mar 13 16:46:46 IST 2019 until: Sun Mar 06 16:46:46 
IST 2044
Certificate fingerprints:
   **SHA1**: A5:32:37:D5:5B:31:6B:B2:09:48:BA:B1:EA:08:8C:RE:CB:23:24:B6
   **SHA256**: 65:89:43:AD:54:65:12:D5:B3:C5:CA:BA:F4:7E:79:02:B5:AE:C9:C5:E8:06:00:1E:C2:10:A5:2E:CE:BF:A3:58
Signature algorithm name: SHA256withRSA
Subject Public Key Algorithm: 2048-bit RSA key
Version: 3
<--output truncated-->
```

How can I get MD5 as well ?

Update:
I am using Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Java : openjdk 10.0.2 2018-07-17

Update : 
`keytool's` -v option also not helping me get MD5 in output.

Answer (score 1):

Select Gradle project from Right side then
app->Tasks->android->signingReport 
Double Click on signingReport after click on then you can see MD5 into Run View.

If you signing keystore file then you should run below command into terminal.
keytool -list -v -keystore C:\Users\MG\Desktop\test.jks -alias test

Comment: Your answer "might" work if I have the source code and keystore. 
I am talking about checking certificate for any random APK.